# Largest representable floating point / Tiny mistake in "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic". 

Tags: language-agnostic, floating-point

I believe there is a tiny mistake in the paper "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic".

It claims that

> A less common situation is that a real number is out of range, that is, its absolute value is larger than
>   [http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/7396/screenshot2011052714105.png http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/7396/screenshot2011052714105.png](http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/7396/screenshot2011052714105.png).

This is almost exact, the maximum representable floating point number is slightly less than that, and the real number is out of range when it is larger than
[http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/9236/screenshot2011052714045.png http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/9236/screenshot2011052714045.png](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/9236/screenshot2011052714045.png)

Right?

Comment: Perhaps "larger than" should be "larger than or equal to".

Comment: Yes that would be correct as well, but not as precise.

Comment: Looks right to me.  Also, you can ditch the `1 +` from your expression if you just make the sum start at `i=0`.

Comment: Wait, that's not right.  Beta is the base, right?  So for example, if beta=10, you want a number like .9999 * 10^n.  I think you need a (beta-1) factor in your sum.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot be bothered with images, so I will write b for "beta" and m for "e_max".

So say b is the base, p is the precision, and m is the max exponent.

Then I think the expression you want is:

```
(1 - b^(-p)) * b^m
```

For example, for base-10 with 4 digits of precision and a max exponent of 12, this gives:

```
.9999 * 10^12
```

...which is correct.

Note that this is not exactly right for IEEE floating point, because there the leading "1" bit is implicit.  And I vaguely recall some oddities when the exponent is all 1's.